# Как получить координаты пикселя в библиотеке PIL

Tags: python, pil

Есть картинка в формате .gif с размером 816x630 и имеются пикселя в виде черного цвет. Как получить координаты данного пикселя черного цвета используя библиотеку PIL?[image: Вот и сама картинка]

Comment: Брать каждый пиксель и смотреть, черный ли он.

Comment: Только начал разбираться с PILом, как выглядит примерно код?

Comment: Код выглядит примерно так: цикл по ширике картинки, внутри цикл по высоте. Определить цвет соответствующего пикселя, если черный, то задача выполнена.

Comment: @Эникейщик, есть ли функция в PIL которая показывает координаты ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
im = Image.open("output.png")
rgb_im = im.convert('RGB')
color = rgb_im.getcolors()
print('Цвета', color)

path = (254, 0, 0)
border = (0, 50, 0)


for x in range(im.size[1]):
    for y in range(im.size[0]):
        pix = rgb_im.getpixel((y, x))
        if pix == path:
            print(f"Цвет: {path}, координаты: {y},{x}!")
```